# Conversão do Alamofire do projecto para swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Tenho o seguinte código quando quero fazer uma chamada ao servidor:

```
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)
            mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["SessionID": sessionID]
do {
     mutableURLRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
   } catch {}

mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(**mutableURLRequest**).responseJSON{

response in if let JSON = response.result.value{}}
```

Onde o texto está a BOLD está a dar-me erro nessa variável

```
Argument type 'NSMutableURLRequest' does not conform to expected type 'URLRequestConvertible'
```

no entanto dão-me a seguinte opção

```
Fix-it Insert as! URLRequestConvertible
```

Se eu aceitar a sugestão é colocado no código o que eles dizem mas o erro persiste e diz para meter outra vez e é isto infinitamente.

Alguem sabe como resolver este problema?

Comment: Apenas uma sugestão. Só usas o Alamofire para fazer pedidos básicos? Porque se for esse o caso, o uso básico de URLSession seria suficiente em vez de andar com uma dependência tão grande como o Alamofire.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves, sim só uso o Alamofire para os pedidos básicos, sou novo a programar em ios e na altura tentei muitas maneiras de fazer pedidos ao servidor e não tive sucesso com nenhum. Até que finalmente com Alamofire deu logo. Consegues postar ou dar um exemplo do URLSession? Obrigado

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta com um exemplo que pode ser colado directamente colado num playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sendo uma resposta directa à pergunta, e para conseguir colocar aqui algum código, queria só indicar uma alternativa ao uso de Alamofire apenas para fazer pedidos HTTP. O Alamofire é um canhão e eu sugiro usá-lo apenas quando necessário. Dito isto, deixo aqui um código que pode ser colado directamente num playground (Xcode 8) e faz um GET a um endpoint da api do Stack overflow.

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    print("response:", response)
    print("error: ", error)

    var responseDictionary: NSDictionary?
    if data != nil {
        do {
            responseDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!,
                                                 options: []) as? NSDictionary
            print(responseDictionary)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }


    }.resume()
```

Comment: Você deveria dar preferencia ao uso do dicionário nativo do Swift3 `[AnyHashable: Any]` ou no caso de um dicionário json `[String: Any]`

Comment: Verdade. É um hábito para de vez em quando usar value(for: keypath) que só há no nsdictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 você deve usar URLRequest em vez de NSURLRequest. Quando for NSMutableURLRequest você também deve usar URLRequest mas como URLRequest é uma structure e não uma classe para poder alterar suas propriedades você precisa declarar o seu objeto como variável em vez de constante. Além disso você ta passando URL onde deveria ser um objeto URL:

```
var mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.exemplo.com")!)
```